# Unable to ping to website

Tags: ip, cmd.exe, ping

I ran cmd as an administrator and I pinged this ip adress "**164.100.118.41**" and it showed **request timed out**,
So I thought it was a connection problem so I restarted the router and just to check the connection
I pinged to google.com and was getting good result,
pinged to some e-learning websites got good result, but again a bad result from 164.100.118.41.
Why is the problem coming? Please help me resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Some hosts do not respond  to ICMP packets. Have you try to access the web site?

Comment: Yeah Ofcourse, It's my was my school's online result website... and i checked it many times..Well, Thank you Responding

Answer (score 1):

A web server will most probably serve web content via port 80 (http) and port 443 (https), unless configured otherwise. Operation of web service is completely different to replying to "ping" messages... it's a different protocol (icmp) and packet type (no port). So, any server might respond to either type of request, a combination of those, or none at all. Even worse: any machine involved in the packet transport might decide to forward specific traffic, or to drop it. Many machines/firewalls do forward http(s), but drop icmp.

Comment: Okay! Got it.Thank you..  So does it means i should shatter my dreams to ping to that website?

Comment: You can download the program paping which allows you to ping specific ports. so paping ipaddress -p 80 would give you what you want.

Comment: I guess ICMP won't work (any more?), but things like paping (which apparently uses a different approach) are still worth a try; good idea @LPChip :)

Comment: Thanx LPChip.... That's awesome yay!... IT WORKED !!! Thank you

Comment: Hey,Just one question... How can i transfer this paping.exe into Linux?Any Idea?

Comment: paping.exe is a windows tool. You'll need a linux equivilent. I don't know one though, and I'm not a linux user. Maybe you can make it work under wine.

Comment: no need for Windows emulation, you can download the paping source and binaries *for Linux* via Google Code (https://code.google.com/p/paping/)

Comment: In all retrospect you could also use telnet on port 80 and see if it replies. Example: telnet 164.100.118.41 80